# Visual studio looks in the proper directory, but stills says that the files aren't found

Tags: visual-c++

I have created my own directory "cpplibs" for storing my library code and the files are there. For whatever reason the "portaudio.sln" file isn't able to properly link to my files. How do I organize my files so that everything gets to the right place, and I don't get any "undefined identifier" or similar errors?

Here is the specific output I am receiving. I did some research or defining directories but still ran into some issues.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: portaudio, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\for visual studio\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(944,5): warning MSB8027: Two or more files with the name of asio.cpp will produce outputs to the same location. This can lead to an incorrect build result.  The files involved are ..\..\..\ASIOSDK2.3.2\common\asio.cpp, ..\..\src\hostapi\asio\ASIOSDK\common\asio.cpp.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\for visual studio\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(944,5): warning MSB8027: Two or more files with the name of asiodrivers.cpp will produce outputs to the same location. This can lead to an incorrect build result.  The files involved are ..\..\..\ASIOSDK2.3.2\host\asiodrivers.cpp, ..\..\src\hostapi\asio\ASIOSDK\host\asiodrivers.cpp.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\for visual studio\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(944,5): warning MSB8027: Two or more files with the name of asiolist.cpp will produce outputs to the same location. This can lead to an incorrect build result.  The files involved are ..\..\..\ASIOSDK2.3.2\host\pc\asiolist.cpp, ..\..\src\hostapi\asio\ASIOSDK\host\pc\asiolist.cpp.
1>cl : Command line warning D9035: option 'Gm' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
1>hostsample.cpp
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\host\sample\hostsample.cpp(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'asiosys.h': No such file or directory
1>asiolist.cpp
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\host\pc\asiolist.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iasiodrv.h': No such file or directory
1>asiodrivers.cpp
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\host\asiodrivers.h(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'asiolist.h': No such file or directory
1>asiodrvr.cpp
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asiodrvr.cpp(16): fatal error C1189: #error:  do not use this
1>asio.cpp
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): error C2011: 'IASIO': 'struct' type redefinition
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asiodrvr.h(26): error C2504: 'IASIO': base class undefined
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(79): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(81): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(87): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(88): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(76): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\string.h(119): note: see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(86): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\string.h(119): note: see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(101): error C2039: 'removeCurrentDriver': is not a member of 'AsioDriver'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asiodrvr.h(26): note: see declaration of 'AsioDriver'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(114): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(121): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(131): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(141): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(151): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(158): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(165): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(172): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(182): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(189): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(196): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(208): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(205): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\string.h(119): note: see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(221): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(228): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(235): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(242): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\asio.cpp(249): error C2027: use of undefined type 'IASIO'
1>c:\program files\cpplibs\asiosdk2.3.2\common\iasiodrv.h(11): note: see declaration of 'IASIO'
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "portaudio.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can build portaudio from a command line:

1. `git clone https://git.assembla.com/portaudio.git`
2. `cd portaudio`
3. `cmake -S .`
4. `msbuild portaudio.sln /m /p:Configuration=Release`

Your output is in `Release` directory.

---

You can download the utilities from:

- git - https://git-scm.com/download/win
- cmake - https://cmake.org/download/
- msbuild - just run '`Developer Command Prompt`' from Windows Start menu

Answer (score -1):

Are you using git in your project ?

I had the same problem and when i removed git from the directory it worked well.

Comment: I don't know if I am using Git, or what that means. I know that the files are all there, or seem to be but it's riddled with issues.What are you suggesting?

Comment: I had this problem too on a git repo cloned from github, and when i tried to download the repo zip instead of cloning it, it worked

Comment: okay, so I need to do what exactly in order to make this specific library work better? What's the problem here? Is it the source of the files or is it the files themselves?

Comment: I took the source directly from the website.